# Pyparsing: what is the purpose of the bitwise shift operator?

Tags: python, pyparsing

I was looking at some of the examples for the [pyparsing](http://pyparsing.wikispaces.com/) module and came across something strange:

```
import sys
import operator
from pyparsing import nums, oneOf, Word, Literal, Suppress
from pyparsing import ParseException, Forward, Group

op_map = { '*' : operator.mul,\
           '+' : operator.add,\
           '/' : operator.div,\
           '-' : operator.sub}

exp = Forward()

number = Word(nums).setParseAction(lambda s, l, t: int(t[0]))
lparen = Literal('(').suppress()
rparen = Literal(')').suppress()
op = oneOf('+ - * /').setResultsName('op').setParseAction(lambda s, l, t: op_map[t[0]])

exp << Group(lparen + op + (number | exp) + (number | exp) + rparen)
```

In the above code, what does the `<<` symbol represent? From the python bitwise operators, it would seem that this is the "shift left" operator. Why is it used here?

Comment: This looks like a prefix notation parser. My original choice of `<<` was unfortunate due to precedence of operators, the preferred operator to use in this case now is `<<=`. As stated in the linked question, this operator is used to "inject" an expression into a previously-declared Forward placeholder. Simple `=` won't work here, since we need to preserve the original object. While any parser can use this form, it is only necessary with recursive grammars.